# m2e plugin in eclipse indigo not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, eclipse-indigo

**1)** Install eclipse with m2e
**2)** Install separately a current maven version (depending on what you need, Maven 2.2.x or Maven 3.0.x)
**3)** Configure your installed Maven inside Eclipse due to the documentation. Do that in the section *Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations.* If that is not visible in Eclipse, you first have to install m2e with the normal installation procedure: *Help > Install New Software > Work with: Indigo > Filter text: m2e > Collaboration > m2e.* Then next, next, next ...
These are the steps that I followed while installing m2e plugin in eclipse.But when I try to create a new maven project, eclipse shows this error
`Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5`

I have found many answers on stack but didn't understand as I am new to maven.Please help
I am using maven 3.0.5 , eclipse indigo 3.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Probably Maven cannot access the Internet, which is often caused by missing proxy settings. Please check your proxy settings in all of these places:

- Eclipse: Windows -> Preferences -> Network (and restart Eclipse afterwards)
- Maven: [${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)